# ionicframework import module, variable always undefined

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to import new features inside my ionicframework project. I executed the following command lines :

> $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid
>
> $ npm install --save @ionic-native/unique-device-id

in my file `MyOwnService.ts`, I'm importing it :

```
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

And then in the constructor of my  `MyOwnService` :

```
  constructor(http: Http, uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID) {
      console.log('Loading provider');
      uniqueDeviceID.get()
          .then((uuid: any) => console.log("UID : " + uuid))
          .catch((error: any) => console.log("UIDERR : " + error));
  }
```

But `uniqueDeviceID` is always undefined. Also http´ doesn't work anymore if I'm adding an extra parameter in the constructor.

Am I missing something ? Do I have to add something in the `app.module.ts` ?

I verified the dir exists in `workspacedir/node_modules/@ionic-native/unique-device-id´`

Comment: did you set UniqueDeviceId as a provider?

Comment: no, MyOwnService is a provider. Must UniqueDeviceID be a provider of a provider ?
I tried to register it as a Provider in the app.module.ts but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

> Must UniqueDeviceID be a provider of a provider ?

Yes. From Ionic-Native 3.x onwards all ionic native services need to be set as provider. Check [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module).

```
@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    UniqueDeviceID
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Secondly, when accessing the plugin, you need to use `this.platform.ready()` like below:

```
 constructor(http: Http, uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID) {
      console.log('Loading provider');
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         uniqueDeviceID.get()
          .then((uuid: any) => console.log("UID : " + uuid))
          .catch((error: any) => console.log("UIDERR : " + error));
      });
  }
```

Also ensure you are testing in an emulator/device as cordova plugins are not enabled when using `ionic serve`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still getting a "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined", but I'm indeed using ionic serve...

I'll try using an emulator, but as i'm intensively working with 'ionic serve' for my tests, is there a way to handle it ?

Comment: you should test in device.